# No danger from these strangers

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

I'm so excited! This is going to be huge! I have no idea who invited me or where it is, but I'm floating on air! WOO!

Okay, so, all the details I have are as follows: I get to meet 7 strangers at a certain rendezvous point this Saturday. Their messenger sent me instructions on where to meet them, and I need your help figuring them out. Also, maybe you can tell me who the strangers are, too.

These two images are all I got in the message:

[image: don't trust web colors]

[image: don't trust web colors]

I'd like to know what I'm getting myself into, so please, tell me where this meeting is, and who the 7 strangers are are. Most importantly, don't judge me.

> **NOTE:** It's come to my attention that the web-rendered colors are different than the real colors. Don't trust the colors as they exist in your browser. All the values should be of the form XXYYZZ. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this puzzle to make it work, or should we just abandon it?

Comment: The more highly voted answer is very close. I think the coordinates were off slightly. Google maps puts 2 sets in the url: one for the pin, and one for the window center. I chose incorrectly. I can tell you, though, that it's a different building in the same complex, and that the date is important

Answer (score 12):

The pictures:

> Show following color values (discarding the color profile and conversions):
>  **#440044 #446622 #eecc88 #55ccff #bb8833**
>  and
>  **#cc0055 #2277ff #00dd22 #bb6611 #aadd99**

Treating them in shorter form:

> #404 #462 #ec8 #5cf #b83
>  #c05 #27f #0d2 #b61 #ad9

and

> concatenating all the digits plus extra "a" from the images gives the following binary data in hex:
>
>  **0x404462ec85cfb83a** and **0xc0527f0d2b61ad9a**
>
>  which (*because you are "floating on air"*) if treated as floating point data ([64 bits IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) decodes to:
>
>  **0x404462ec85cfb83a = 40.7728431**
>  **0xc0527f0d2b61ad9a = -73.9851780**
>
>  and if treated as earth coordinates points to [here](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.7728431,-73.985178,18z) - The Metropolitan Opera in NY, but most probably in general to Lincoln Center where there are several events on Saturday. The only one I could find with 7 strangers is the play ["War"](http://www.lincolncenter.org/show/war-1) (*which may refer to "danger" from the title*) and the characters are Tobias, Malcolm, Tate, Joanne, Elfriede, Nurse Alpha and Roberta (*two of whom are announced like strangers, BTW*).

So on Saturday:

> you are going in NY, Lincoln Center, to watch the play "War" with Tobias, Malcolm, Tate, Joanne, Elfriede, Nurse Alpha and Roberta

Comment: You're super close. I don't know how this keeps happening, but there must be some floating point weirdness. I'll just tell you I picked a different building at Lincoln Center.

Comment: @Matt I was lost in all the buildings, halls, events... Nothing useful I can find so far. So, if someone else wants to let continue.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

> The images have the following color codes:
>  #450045 #43671D #EFCD83 #4ECBFF #BC8928
>  and
>  #CE0053 #1873FF #00DF00 #BD6600 #A9DE96
>
>  These correspond to dec values of:
>   4522053 4417309 15715715  5164031 12355880
>  13500499 1602559    57088 12412416 11132566

The first 2 pairs of Lat and Long correspond to:

> Primorsky Krai, Russia, 692101
>  Kom, Croatia

Not sure if this will lead anywhere.

Comment: Check the images again, in a downloaded version.  There's an issue with the way they're rendering on the site.

Comment: I updated the puzzle to reflect this, as well. Thanks, @Khale_Kitha